# What is a good free linux antivirus?

Tags: antivirus

A simple question today, need help deciding on a quality free antivirus system.

Comment: this should be on [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need an antivirus.
But anyways, there's a free, open-source anti-virus called ClamAV. It detects trojans and malwares.
Source code :
https://github.com/Cisco-Talos/clamav
Install :

```
sudo apt install clamav
```

It's a cli-based tool, You can see how to use it from the internet or just running `man clamav`

also there's a gui one called clamtk

To install it run :

```
sudo apt install clamtk
```

Comment: Recent windows convert, I get twitch w/o an antivirus. Thanks! I'll take the recommendation.

Comment: how is this a duplicate issue when all questions on the first page are 5+ years old?